# Python: using a counter to save multiple files with unique names

Tags: python, loops, file, save

I have the following code which collects certain strings in a log file using a loop:

```
skip_line = True  
writefile = open("input_nn.txt", "a")  
with open("input_n.txt","r") as myfile:  
     for line in myfile:  
        if "Distance" in line:  
            skip_line = True  
        elif "Input" in line:  
            skip_line = False  
        else:  
            pass  
        if skip_line:  
            continue  
        writefile.write(line)`
```

To this loop I want to add a line(s) which saves the output after the elif statement to a new .scr/.txt file each time it goes through this loop.

I've seen posts which do this for arrays of numbers however those loops work since the values of the arrays can be called by index. I have no clue how to do it in this case since I'll be saving lines of strings to different files.

Comment: Are you saying that each chunk from "Input" to "Distance" should be written to a new file?  If so, just set a counter to zero, and when you find "Input", bump the counter and open a new file.

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 0  
f = open('innput.txt','r')  
always_print = False  
with f as fp:  
    lines = fp.readlines()  
    for line in lines:  
       if ' X ' in line:   #This is the string we will separate the file by
           i += 1  
           ff = open('dipole_'+str(i)+'.com','a') #unique naming  
           always_print = True  
       elif 'Input' in line:  
           always_print = False  
       elif always_print:  
           ff.write(line)  
       else:  
           pass  
       if always_print:  
          continue
```

So this basically means whenever 'X' shows up in the file, the counter (i) adds and a new file is made dipole_i.com where i is the iteration number, so in this case it'll open and write to dipole_1, dipole_2 and so on. The elif 'Input' in line tells python to stop writing lines in the new file so that only the text you want is therethe last bit runs over the rest of the file so that it doesn't stop at the first occurrence.

Comment: Could you explain why this works?